# KDE Neon 5.17; Unable to download any files from Internet , Including sudo apt-get update

Tags: networking, kde, kde-neon

I got a fresh install of KDE Neon, the latest stable version. The first network problem I noticed was that my wifi had "limited Connectivity". I "solved" this issue by running `sudo systemctl restart network-manager`. I then tried to open Discover, the default KDE Software center, and I couldnt install apps, update or do anything. Sudo apt-get install also doesnt work, "connection failed." I know this isn't my Wifi that's having problems, as this network works perfectly fine on Windows, and MacOS on other devices.